# Awkward moment at department meeting

Tags: meetings

I zoned out in my department meeting (about 80 people) and suddenly heard my name in the department award session. I was still thinking what I did to get the award so didn’t stand up to accept my trophy.... and the host went on to the next award. Is it really bad? I was really embarrassed afterwards because lots of people stared at me..

Answer (score 10):

What's done is done.

Forget about it move on. Next time, be more attentive at the meeting. Your employer is paying you to be attentive.